# How to add tabs at bottom

Tags: android, tabs

I have a tabhost which contains three tabs, connected with three activities. All three tabs are in the upper side. How can I make these three tabs at the bottom?

I found this, but there are still some problems.

This is my tabhost XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

In my TabActivity class, I have following code:

```
setContentView(R.layout.tabs);

TabHost mTabHost = (TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);

mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab_test1").setIndicator("TAB 1").setContent(new Intent(AndroisTabViewActivity.this,TabActivity1.class)));
mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab_test2").setIndicator("TAB 2").setContent(new Intent(AndroisTabViewActivity.this,TabActivity1.class)));
mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab_test3").setIndicator("TAB 3").setContent(new Intent(AndroisTabViewActivity.this,TabActivity1.class)));

mTabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
```

There is one activity named TabActivity1 which I have also included in Manifest file. But it is showing the error:

> Can't get the activity TabActivity1.

Comment: Have you included AndroisTabViewActivity in the Manifest file? Please show what kind of error are you receiving. Maybe it's not even related to registering activities in manifest.

Comment: Yes i included it into manifest file.I dont know how to get your log cat pic.So I will write the errors.Just wait.

Comment: Here is my error: Unable To Start activityComponentInfo{com.mirza.tabViewDemo/com.mirza.tabViewDemo.AndroisTabViewActivity}:android.content.ActivityNotFoundException explicit activity class{com.mirza.tabViewDemo/com.mirza.tabViewDemo.TabActivity1}

Comment: If you are using Eclipse, open the **Application** tab of the Manifest, and try to add the TabActivity1 using the UI, at Application Nodes, the buttons **Add..** and then **Browse..** for the name, maybe there is just a spelling mistake.

Comment: I just type wrongly in manifest file. I typed activty instead of activity.Sorry all guys. :d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to show "Tab" at **bottom** of the window, just try this:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TabWidget
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
    </TabWidget>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent">
    </FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks.Your code also worked and mine too.I just type wrongly in manifest file. I typed activty instead of activity.Sorry all guys. :d

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the `LinearLayout`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

With this solution, the `tab content` will take no space firstly, the `TabWidget` will take its own space, then the remaining space will be given to the `tab content`.